# Is Spring XA transactions across non-transactional backends feasible at all?

Tags: spring, transactions, xa

I'm writing an application that has to communicate across 3 different platforms.  Two expose their DB via a REST API (no jdbc driver) and one is a native JDBC connection (ex: Derby, MySQL, Oracle, etc).

My problem is that I have no way of assuring any ACID'ity when updating data, given that the three should be updated at the same time.

I've tried reading up on Spring XA but it seems as both 2PC and 1PC require some form of transactional backends.  Given that 2 of my 3 destinations are REST APIs, I don't have any transactions.  Just a save/update option.

Are there techniques I can use to ensure that the 3 sources are synchronized and that I don't run into inconsistent states if ever a write fails (ie: REST endpoint unavialble, etc)?

A transaction example would be:

1. Read from DB
2. Write to REST-1 endpoint
3. Update DB
4. Write to REST-2 endpoint

Is there some form of XA I could employ to wrap everything in such a way I can be assured of consistency?

Comment: When using distributed services like this you enter the arena of the [CAP theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem) and Eventual Consistency. In short no you don't for SOAP there are some WS-* "standards" that attempt to provide transaction support. For REST there is no such thing.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for the confirmation.  Pretty much what I had figured, but wasn't sure if there was something I didn't know about.